# Getting "404 Not Found" when accessing Exchange 2007 mail store using WebDAV

Tags: http-status-code-404, webdav, exchange-server-2007

I am trying to access the Exchange 2007 mail store programmatically using WebDAV.  However, for some users I am getting the dreaded error "404 Not found".  I am using a url similar to http://server/exchange/usermailbox/.  It is working just fine for some users but not for others.

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if I use the default SMTP address of the users it works just fine - i. e. I am using a url similar to server/exchange/user@domain.local when accessing the Exchange store. You can find the default SMTP address from the proxyAdresses property for the user in Active Directory. The default address is the one where SMTP is capitalized.